# After creating android project in Eclipse ADT, tons of errors show up

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse ADT (most recent version) to develop some android apps. I've followed the getting started tutorial at the dev.android.com and it worked just fine.

But when i tried to create another project with the same targets and sdk's, i've got nothing but errors:

Some errors and my sdk's:

[image]
[image]

That's the same sdk's i used before these errors started showing up.
What can be causing this?

EDIT: my project won't generate the R.java file

Comment: Have you tried Project > Clean. That usually fixes these erroes

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add a support library to your new project.

Check this link for downloading the support libraries -

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download

Please notice that you need to import them into your eclipse and then include one (preferably the newest, not sure about this) in your project.

EDIT:
Before downloading the support libraries you should first check if you have them already.
Try this, right click project folder in the eclipse package explorer, Properties>Android>Library>Add>*select a library if you have one*.
There might be an invalid library included in your project already, if that happens then you will see it in the Library>Add> menu, remove it and add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You might have clean your project ........
**if yes.**....you must check whether R.java file is present in ****Project(your project)->gen->package name->R.java****

**if not** than u have to **update Tool Folder** in **SDK manager**

Comment: I did clean the project. But i didn't update the tool folder in sdk manager...i'll check it out.

Comment: Well, i tried everything i could do...the only thing that worked was extracting my bundle again...and download all the sdk's...T_T